# The は particle following a noun's わ?

Tags: particle-は

I was looking for improvements on my vocabulary and then I saw the word `telephone` which accordinly to Genki series is でんわ, but let's suppose that I want to say `This telephone is white`, is gramatically correct to say この**でんわ**はしろです.

Can I say both は and わ? Sounding something like `kono denwa wa shiro desu`? Or should I choose another word (if there is one) to replace でんわ to not mess up the noun with the particle?

Comment: I think it's normal, you can repeat wa sound twice in a row and it's ok, the same is for ga "manga ga hoshii" and probably most sounds. Even in portuguese that happens as well "ele está na caMA MAs não quer levantar"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would still pronounce it `wa.`  You will not have to change the reading of the は particle just because a noun ends in わ.  Here's another example:

> Excuse me, but this conversation is boring.
>
> すみません、この会話｛かいわ｝はつまらないです。

In Japanese, repeated sounds like this are not uncommon, and should not be a reason for concern.

Comment: Well I was actually thinking about changing the noun *telephone* but not the particle は. But now I know that there is no problem repeating the `wa` sound, although just for academic purposes, are there any other words for *telephone*?

Comment: @JoãoBrgai Not really.  Some people use `けいたい`, but that's short for `けいたいでんわ,` or mobile phone.  Saying けいたい is like saying `mobile` in English.

Comment: @JoãoBrgai, でんわ works for any kind of telephone, land-lines and cell-phones alike.  けいたいでんわ is a mobile phone, never a land line.  けいたい is the same, but faster to say.  Most of the time, however, you'll hear でんわ, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: What about 3 in a row:  この会話はワクワク!

Comment: Or even 三日掛かるか?